# Interleave two numpy arrays based on element distances (python)

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have two arrays, which can look like this:

```
X = np.array([ 157,  262,  368,  472,  577,  682,  786,  891,  996, 1100, 1204,
       1310, 1415, 1520, 1625, 1731, 1879])

Y = np.array([  30,  135,  240,  345,  450,  555,  660,  765,  870,  975, 1080,
       1185, 1290, 1395, 1500, 1605])
```

The arrays will:

- Have values sorted in ascending order from start.
- Be of unequal length at times.

I want to interleave these two into a new array `Z` based on the following:

- Each element may only be used once
- All elements need not be used
- An element `Xi` may only be included in `Z` if there is an element `Yj` in `Y` such that there are no other elements in `Y` with value difference smaller than `abs(Xi - Yj)` and that there are no element in `X` for which the value distance to `Yj` is smaller than `abs(Xi - Yj)`. (The same rule applies to elements in `Y`.)

I see that I can do this with a bunch of nested for loops, but I wonder if there is some smarter, neater way of doing this?

(I realize, the way I put the question, that it sounds like cut from a textbook. It is not. But maybe it is a classic sort function, who knows, but for me as a biologist... all I can say is I'm at a loss as how to solve it in an efficient, neat way.)

**Edit: Not so pretty example**

```
new_list = list()
for i in X:
    delta_i = np.abs(Y - i)
    delta_reciprocal = np.abs(X - Y[delta_i.argmin()])
    if delta_i.min() == delta_reciprocal.min():
        new_list += sorted([Y[delta_i.argmin()],
        X[delta_reciprocal.argmin()]])
Z = np.array(new_list)
```

I'm not even totally sure it fulfills all the criteria, but when rewriting the old code I got down to just one loop... still there must be some nicer way!

Comment: it would help if you put your own attempts at solving this, for others to examine and improve upon. also it will be simpler to read code then to try to understand your logic for some people here.

Comment: I agree with @InbarRose -- If you show us how it could be solved (inelegantly/inefficiently) with loops, it might make the problem easier to understand.

Comment: I'll have some old code I'll have to adapt. I'll be back in a minute

Comment: honestly if that code you posted does the job - it does not seem so bad. wrap it in a function and it is passable+

Comment: I think it was a be premature question of me, at the end of the workday I agree...but I'll let it be if anyone stumbles upon the same problem again... or if there's a numpy wizard that directly spots the function I should have used...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try to work out the solution for this example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [5]: X = np.array([1879, 1731])

In [6]: Y = np.array([1481, 1691, 1586, 1796])
```

We can compute all the distances between values in `X` and values in `Y` like this:

```
In [7]: dist = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(X,Y))

In [8]: dist
Out[8]: 
array([[398, 188, 293,  83],
       [250,  40, 145,  65]])
```

The rows correspond to `X` values, the columns correspond to `Y` values.

To find the `X` values which are closest to some element in `Y`, we are looking
for the `X` which corresponds to a minimum value in a *column* of the `dist`
matrix. Each column corresponds to a particular `Y`, so the minimum distance in
a column corresponds to the minimum between some `X` and a particular `Y`.

Visually speaking, what we are looking for are values in `dist` which are
minimums for **both** the row that they are in, **and** the column that they are
in. Let's call them "row-column minimums".

In the `dist` array above, 40 is a row-column minimum. 65 is a column-minimum,
but not a row-column minimum.

For each column, we can find the X-index which minimizes the column this way:

```
In [6]: idx1 = np.argmin(dist, axis = 0)

In [7]: idx1
Out[7]: array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Similarly, for each row, we can find the Y-index this way:

```
In [8]: idx2 = np.argmin(dist, axis = 1)

In [9]: idx2
Out[9]: array([3, 1])
```

Now, let's forget about this example for a second and suppose `idx1` looked like this:

```
        0,1,2,3,4,5   # the index value 
idx1 = (_,_,_,_,_,2,...)
```

This is saying in the 5th column, row 2 has the minimum value.

Then if row 2, column 5 were to correspond to a row-column minimum, then `idx2`
would have to look like this:

```
        0,1,2        # index value
idx2 = (_,_,5,...)
```

We can express this relationship in NumPy with

```
idx1[idx2] == np.arange(len(X))
idx2[idx1] == np.arange(len(Y))
```

So the X, Y values which correspond to row-column minimums are

```
X[idx1[idx2] == np.arange(len(X))]
```

and

```
Y[idx2[idx1] == np.arange(len(Y))]
```

---

```
import numpy as np
tests = [
    (np.array([1879, 1731]),
     np.array([1481, 1691, 1586, 1806])), 
    (np.array([1879, 1731]),
     np.array([1481, 1691, 1586, 1796])),
    (np.array([ 157,  262,  368,  472,  577,  682,  786,  891,  996, 1100, 1204]),
     np.array([  30,  135,  240,  345,  450,  555,  660,  765,  870,  975])),
    (np.array([ 157, 262, 368, 472, 577, 682, 786, 891, 996, 1100, 1204, 1310,
                1415, 1520, 1625, 1731, 1879]),
     np.array([ 221, 326, 431, 536, 641, 746, 851, 956, 1061, 1166, 1271, 1376,
                1481, 1586, 1691, 1796]))]

def find_close(X,Y):
    new_list = list()
    for i in X:
        delta_i = np.abs(Y - i)
        # print(delta_i)
        delta_reciprocal = np.abs(X - Y[delta_i.argmin()])
        if delta_i.min() == delta_reciprocal.min():
            new_list += sorted([Y[delta_i.argmin()],
                                X[delta_reciprocal.argmin()]])
    Z = np.array(new_list)
    return Z

def alt_find_close(X,Y):
    dist = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(X,Y))
    idx1 = np.argmin(dist, axis = 0)
    idx2 = np.argmin(dist, axis = 1)
    Z = np.r_[X[idx1[idx2] == np.arange(len(X))], Y[idx2[idx1] == np.arange(len(Y))]]
    return Z

for X, Y in tests:
    assert np.allclose(sorted(find_close(X,Y)), sorted(alt_find_close(X,Y)))
```

---

Timeit results:

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.find_close(test.X, test.Y)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 454 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.alt_find_close(test.X, test.Y)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.6 usec per loop
```

So `alt_find_close` is significantly faster than `find_close`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was some nice way of doing this!

Comment: After trying your algorithm some more I found it sometimes returns an odd-length array (which the interleave premise forbids) at times. E.g. if `X = np.array([ 157,  262,  368,  472,  577,  682,  786,  891,  996, 1100, 1204, 1310, 1415, 1520, 1625, 1731, 1879])` and `Y = np.array([ 221,  326,  431,  536,  641,  746,  851,  956, 1061, 1166, 1271, 1376, 1481, 1586, 1691, 1796])`

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I gotta read through it one or two more times to be sure I get all the points.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to use `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` (you could build such thing yourself with numpys `searchsorted` but I don't see much of  a point, unless maybe to have more control over problems with equal distances).

However generally you should be carefull. Your examples are integer arrays, and depending on which occurance is found there might be problems (argmin always finds the first so maybe it does not matter, but for this one you may drop points if you have equal distances).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

def find_close_fast(X, Y):
    kX = cKDTree(X[:,None]) # needs to be 2D
    kY = cKDTree(Y[:,None])

    nearest_X = kX.query(Y[:,None], p=1)[1] # might as well use 1-norm

    # Which Y corresponds the other way around?
    nearest_Y = kY.query(X[nearest_X][:,None], p=1)[1]

    w = nearest_Y == np.arange(len(Y))
    result = np.concatenate((X[nearest_X[w]], Y[w]))
    return result
```

This will be *much* faster if your arrays get large (maybe around a few hundred each). For example:

```
In [121]: X = np.random.random(5000)

In [122]: Y = np.random.random(5000)

In [123]: %timeit alt_find_close(X, Y)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop

In [124]: %timeit find_close_fast(X, Y)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.3 ms per loop

In [125]: np.all(np.sort(find_close_fast(X,Y)) == np.sort(alt_find_close(X, Y))) 
Out[125]: True
```

But I used floating point numbers here for a reason, the results are not ensured if you can have equal distances. The sorting is different, didn't really try to figure out why exactly.

Edit: Actually you could also sort both arrays into one (and remember which one belongs to which class), then go from there by checking where two of the different class are next to each other. And if a point has two neighbours of the other class, pick the closer one by hand. That is probably even faster and uses only numpy.

Comment: I'll have to check that out tomorrow, but it sure also looks promising